# Can you adjust how long appengine's appcfg remembers passwords?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm regularly releasing a Google Appengine application through the command line utility `appcfg.sh`/`appcfg.cmd`. Unfortunately, the cookie that stores my password has a short expiration time; a week or less. Is it possible to extend this period?

Answer (score 4):

Why not use an [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#oauth) token instead of using password based authentication?

It is more convenient and can be permanently stored, no more typing passwords!

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want, but unfortunately it's not available in the Java SDK. An old habit got me to write appcfg.py, but that was wrong. I've updated the question to say appcfg.sh instead. Thanks for your answer still.

Comment: You should file an issue in the issue tracker to get support added to the Java SDK.

Comment: That's a fine idea: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7653

Comment: It's available now with SDK 1.7.2.